# What does Swift 2.0 being released to linux mean for developing iOS apps?

Tags: ios, linux, swift

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=29

Does this necessarily mean we should be able to develop iOS / OSX apps on Linux?

Yes, no or maybe?

Comment: Language ≠ platform. Swift the language will be present on Linux, but Cocoa or Cocoa-Touch won't. I guess Apple's goal is for non-Apple developpers to be able to use Swift with other platforms, but it doesn't mean they will be able to use Apple's environment.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this necessarily mean we should be able develop iOS / OSX apps on Linux.

**No**, it does not necessarily mean that you will be able to develop iOS or OS X applications using Linux. A compiler is just one of the tools required to produce an application for a given platform.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to develop iOS/OS X apps on Linux, just the compiler will be available, not the Cocoa/Foundation frameworks.
Developers will be able to compile swift code on linux. I think we'll see a lot of web applications written in swift soon.

Comment: Seeing as the web apps sphere is already saturated with plenty of programming languages, and Mac Servers arn't common for use as web apps, I doubt many people will make the switch.

Plus with Ruby on Rails, and Flask/Django for Python, why would someone use a compiled language?  And if they do, wouldn't they use Java, as that's been a standard for a long time?

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C has already been available on Linux for decades.

Does this mean we are able to develop iOS / OSX apps on Linux? No.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone else is being pessimistic, I'll at least try to be mildly optimistic. While everything above is true, swift programs call apple's API functions to do much of the system/visual integration and linux won't have that, since the language is higher level, it may make it easier to build an interpreter for the API function calls to match functionality (like WINE for windows or the fabled Darling [based on GNUstep] for Apple that kinda exists a little already). Sooooo maaaaaaybe?